# How to restore EFS from windows.old folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup, encryption, certificate

I recently crashed my computer and I couldn't repair my Windows XP installation so I decided to upgrade it to Windows 7 (I didn't format) my old system files were saved in the `Windows.old` folder.

However, I forgot about my Encrypted files, EFS and certificates. So now I have encrypted files with no certificates or keys.

I wonder if there is a way I can transfer my key and certificates to the new OS?

Comment: Do you still have the "Documents and Settings" folder?

Comment: Without the key there is no way to recover your files

Comment: yes i still have  "Documents and Settings" folder

Comment: What happened to your normal backups?

Comment: IIRC the EFS certificate is tied to your user account, so you’ll have to look there.

Comment: i have no backups. :(
i couldn't find pfx files in windows.old

Answer (score 0):

As per [this Q/A](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46915/how-to-recover-efs-cert-from-backup), what you’re trying to do is not possible:

> Q: I made a backup of the old Win 7 Pro then did a clean install. But I forgot to export my EFS encryption certificate [...]
>
> A: [...] You have to boot into the old system, export the certificate with the corresponding private key and save it (I saved it as PFX). [...]

Microsoft offers some [background info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962112.aspx) on how your private EFS key is encrypted. The key is constructed with:

> - A symmetric encryption of the user's master key produced by 160-bit RC4.
> - The user's security identifier (SID).
> - The user's logon password.